# get users ip address in Laravel without installing packages

Tags: php, laravel

My site is trilingual ,I have a problem now, Normally, the site is in Persian language and users first see the Persian site and can change the language of the site from the language change option. How can the language be changed according to the IP of the visitor?
For example :Persian language users, by opening the site, view the site in Persian , Arabic-speaking users, by opening the site, see the site in Arabic .this is the method that used for change language.

controller:

```
 public function index($locale) //en | fa
{

    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session()->put('local', $locale);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

app/config:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',



'locale' => 'fa',

'fallback_locale' => 'fa',
```

dropdown menu:

```
    <div class="dropdown show nav-link">
    @php $local =Session()->get('local'); @endphp
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle " href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="{{asset('images/translate/translate.png')}}" width="40px" height="40px">

        @switch($local)
            @case('fa')
            فارسی
            @break
            @case('en')
            English
            @break
            @case('ar')
            العربی
            @break
        @endswitch

    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item text-right nav-link " href="{{route('language','fa')}}"><img
                    src="{{asset('images/translate/iran.png')}}"
                    width="30" height="30"
            >
            فارسی</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-right nav-link" href="{{route('language','en')}}"> <img
                    src="{{asset('images/translate/english.png')}}" width="30" height="30"
            >English</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-right nav-link" href="{{route('language','ar')}}"> <img
                    src="{{asset('images/translate/emarat.png')}}" width="30" height="30"
            >العربی</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rout

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'LocalizationController@index')->name('language');
```

Answer (score 1):

salaam.

You can get the user IP from `request()` method that is available in every request (every route). For example in your `index` method:

```
 public function index($locale) //en | fa
{
    $userIp = request()->ip();
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session()->put('local', $locale);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Comment: were we can find that where is this ip ?

Comment: @melissapoorkamaly without installing any packages I would say this is impossible. Personally I use https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/ along with the [geoip](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) databases but this is not too accurate

Comment: @apokryfos this package(GeoIP2-php) in not good for laravel

Comment: @melissapoorkamaly do you have any issues using it? I've been using it in my company for a while and it's working ok for me. Need to keep the db somewhere accessible but that's all the setup I needed

Comment: @apokryfos   yes its composer does not install

Comment: @ apokryfos  I am using  Torann /laravel-geoip too ,but its composer does not install